# Boolean algebra-dual of an expression

Tags: boolean-algebra

Can anyone think of an expression that is equal to its dual ? I've been trying to solve this for the past 2 hours, but nothing comes to mind.

Comment: According to Wiki : [Boolean algebra : Duality principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra) : $(x∧y) ∨ (y∧z) ∨ (z∧x)$. I think that it needs quite a lot of patience to check it...